# StartUp Folder Removed but Applications still start up automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, startup, taskmanager

I accidentally removed my Startup Folder in AppsData so the StartUp Tab in my Task Manager is empty. However, some applications still start up automatically. What do I do in order to stop these applications from starting up? I'm afraid that my BIOS will take a long time to start up once I download more programs in my PC.

Answer (score 1):

There are several places in Windows which specify start-up programs. You can see the full list using the `msconfig.exe` utility.

More details here: https://www.howtogeek.com/74523/how-to-disable-startup-programs-in-windows/

Also, note that some programs register themselves as "services" and started by the Windows Service Manager, so you might take a look on `"Control Panel"->"Administrative tools"->"Services"`. But be careful, most of the stuff there is essential for normal system operation.